# Text next to the line between rows of a table

Tags: tables

I've had a question recently on tables and here is my second dilemma. ( I am pretty new in LaTeX)

I do not know how to write something next to the line between 2 rows of a table. I know I should somehow merge the rows and align but I do not know how to put that in my code that I have so far. My teacher helped me so far but he does not know either.

Please help. First picture is what it should look like and second is how mine looks

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & {\hskip-3mm{$b_1$}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}{{\hskip-3mm{$b_1'$}}} &  \\
 \cline{2-3}
  & & & $b_3'$ \\
 \cline{2-4}
 $b_2$ & & & \\
 \cline{1-3}
  & & & $b_3$ \\
 \cline{2-4}
 $b_2'$ & & & $b_3'$ \\
 \cline{2-3}
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image: how it should look]
[image: how mine looks]

Comment: The `\multirow` command can be used to position b3

Comment: Could you please explain why you used `\hskip-3mm`?

Comment: to just try and arrange it

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions using `multirow` and a `tabular` or an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & {\hskip-3mm{$b_1$}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}{{\hskip-3mm{$b_1'$}}} &  \\
 \cline{2-3}
  & & & $b_3'$ \\
 \cline{2-4}
 \multirow{-2}{*}{$b_2$} & & & \\
 \cline{1-3}
  & & & \multirow{-2}{*}{$b_3$} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 \multirow{-2}{*}{$b_2'$} & & & $b_3'$ \\
 \cline{2-3}
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\[
 \begin{array}{l|l|l|l}
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{b_1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{b_1'} &  \\
 \cline{2-3}
  & & & b_3' \\
 \cline{2-4}
 \multirow{-2}{*}{$b_2$} & & & \\
 \cline{1-3}
  & & & \multirow{-2}{*}{$b_3$} \\
 \cline{2-4}
 \multirow{-2}{*}{$b_2'$} & & & b_3' \\
 \cline{2-3}
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that with `hhline` (requires `colortbl`, which is loaded by the `table` option of `xcolor`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.8ex}
 \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & $b_1^{}$ & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$b_1'$}\\
 \hhline{~|--|
 ~}
  & & & $b_3'$ \\
\hhline{~>{\llap{\smash{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{$b_2$}}\,}}|---|}
\hphantom{$b_3$} & & \\
\hhline{--->{\rlap{\,\smash{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{$b_3$}}}}~}
  & & & \\
\hhline{~>{\llap{\smash{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{$b'_2$}}\,}}|---|}
 & & & $b_3'$ \\
 \hhline{~|--|}
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]